# A Problem About Circular Motion

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

> A $2$ $\text {kg}$ ball on a string is rotated about a circle of
>   radius $10 \text {m}$. The maximum tension allowed in the string is
>   $50$ $\text {N}$.
>
> - What is the maximum speed of the ball?

May I get your helps for this question? I'm trying to find the correct equation.

Comment: there are other forces acting on this ball? It is rotating how?

Comment: If I tie a lightweight piece of string to a 2 kg ball, then run around the circumference of a 10 m circle with the string trailing behind me, the ball will be rotated around the circle, the tension in the string will never be anywhere near 50 N, and the maximum speed of the ball will be just as fast as I can run. That's a whimsical interpretation of the problem statement, but it is an example of what kind of information you're missing.

Comment: Is it rotating in a plane such that the normal force equals the weight?:

Comment: Assuming the other end of the string is tied to a fixed pivot and the distance from the pivot to the ball is always the length of the string, there is a difference between a ball sliding on a frictionless surface around a pivot in the plane of its circle, or a ball supported only by the string in a gravitational field--and in the latter case it makes a difference whether the plane of the circle is horizontal or vertical.

Comment: @DavidK What am i missing, sir?

Comment: The problem statement is missing any description whatsoever of how the ball is made to rotate around the circle, or any other considerations such as gravity (which I suspect we're supposed to ignore, but there's nothing that says we should). The problem statement doesn't even say that the other end of the string is attached to anything. Maybe the question was just that bad when it was given to you, but when you come here with an ill-defined question (even if it's not your fault) you can expect it to be nit-picked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about rotational motion. Usually there are two cases :

$\textbf{Horizontal motion case}$ : Just use Newton's eq
$$
F_{\text{sent}}=ma_{\text{sent}}=m v^2/r
$$
in this setting the total force is just tension $T$. So,
$$
T_{\text{max}} = m v_{\text{max}}^2/r \implies v_{\text{max}} = \sqrt{rT_{\text{max}}/m}
$$

$\textbf{Vertical motion case}$ : If the motion is vertical, it will be quite different, because now the gravitational force enter the equation. So the tension is varies depend on the position of the ball due to the gravity.

[image]

When this is the case, a little refrection on the free body diagram should convince you that the maximum tension happen when the ball is happen to be at the bottom. So
$$
T_{\text{max}} - mg  = m v_{\text{max}}^2/r \implies v_{\text{max}} = \sqrt{\frac{r}{m}(T_{\text{max}}-mg) }
$$

Answer (score 1):

Following Corollary $1$, Prop. $4$, Book I, of Newton's Principia, in this circular motion$$f=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$so we should have$$50=\frac{2v^2}{10}$$from which we get$$v=\sqrt250=15.81\frac{m}{sec}$$

Answer (score 0):

I assume they mean the maximum possible speed of the ball. Use the equation for the centripetal force, $F_c=\frac{mv^2}{r}$, where $v$ is the velocity, $m$ is the mass of the ball and $r$ is the radius. The string exerts this force on the ball, so by newton's third law the ball will exert the same force on the string in outward radial direction. This force can be $50N$ at max, so $v^2$ can be $\frac{50r}{m}$ at max, so $v$ can be at most $\sqrt{\frac{50r}{m}}$. I leave it to you to fill in the numbers.